# Cube drawing is shifted

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a cube in TiKz. The cube is centered at the origin. That is
the coordinates are (±1,±1,±1) still when I display the cube is shifted. Aligned at x=0, and all in the first (all positive coordinates) cuadrant.

Here is a simplified example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,decorations.markings, backgrounds, positioning,intersections,shapes}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}

      %\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{145}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

          \coordinate (A) at (1,-1,1);
          \coordinate (B) at (-1,-1,1);
          \coordinate (C) at (-1,1,1);
          \coordinate (D) at (1,1,1);
          \coordinate (E) at (1,1,-1);
          \coordinate (F) at (-1,1,-1);
          \coordinate (G) at (-1,-1,-1);
          \coordinate (H) at (1,-1,-1);

          \draw[fill=black] (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$A$};
          \draw[fill=black] (B) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$B$};
          \draw[fill=black] (C) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$C$};
          \draw[fill=black] (D) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$D$};
          \draw[fill=black] (E) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$E$};
          \draw[fill=black] (F) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$F$};
          \draw[fill=black] (G) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west] {$G$};
          \draw[fill=black] (H) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$H$};
          \draw[fill=blue] (O) circle (1pt) node[anchor=east] {$0$};

          \coordinate (X) at (3,0,0);
          \coordinate (Y) at (0,3,0);
          \coordinate (Z) at (0,0,3);


          \draw[opacity=0.2] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
          \draw[opacity=0.2] (E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--cycle;
          \draw[opacity=0.2] (A)--(H);
          \draw[opacity=0.2] (B)--(G);
          \draw[opacity=0.2] (D)--(E);
          \draw[opacity=0.2] (C)--(F);



          \draw[-latex] (O) -- (X) node[anchor=west] {\; \; $X$};
          \draw[-latex] (O) -- (Y) node[anchor=south] {$Y$};
          \draw[-latex] (O) -- (Z) node[anchor=south] {$Z$};



      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

and here the figure:

[image: cube is shifted]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is optical illusion.

You can change the perspective by `z=(...)`. 
Here is your code simplified and with extended axes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,z={(-.5,-.28)}]

    \draw[latex-] (2.1,0,0) coordinate (X) node[anchor=west] {$X$} -- ([scale=-1]X);
    \draw[latex-] (0,2.1,0) coordinate (Y) node[anchor=south] {$Y$} -- ([scale=-1]Y);
    \draw[latex-] (0,0,3.5) coordinate (Z) node[anchor=east] {$Z$} -- ([scale=-1]Z);

    \draw[fill=blue]  coordinate (O) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south  east] {$O$};

    \draw[opacity=0.2]
      (1,-1,1)   coordinate (A) --
      (-1,-1,1)  coordinate (B) --
      (-1,1,1)   coordinate (C) --
      (1,1,1)    coordinate (D) -- cycle
      (1,1,-1)   coordinate (E) --
      (-1,1,-1)  coordinate (F) --
      (-1,-1,-1) coordinate (G) --
      (1,-1,-1)  coordinate (H) -- cycle
      (A)--(H) (B)--(G) (D)--(E) (C)--(F);

    \foreach \l/\a in {A/north west,B/north east,C/south east,D/south east,E/south west,F/south east,G/north west,H/north west}
      \draw[fill=black] (\l) circle (1pt) node[anchor=\a] {$\l$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accept your answer. Thank you very much. I have a hard time believing Kurt's argument about "optical illusion" .  Look at the points G and B in my original cube. Is it an illusion that they are lying in the Z axis?

Comment: Yes, it is an illusion. When you project 3D to 2D there are always points that look like this. Put `z=(-.5,-.5)` and you will be back with B and G on the Z axis ;)

Comment: I believe you are  right.  The coordinate G=(-1,-1,-1) is in the negative plane of the Z axis and in my plot it looks in the positive..... Even more, all coordinates look in the positive side. I have seen optical illusions but this one is quite deceiving.  Thanks.